# JQuery UI AutoComplete: .data(...) is undefined [but only when I am add a second autocomplete box]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using JQuery 1.8.3 and JQuery UI 1.8.24.

This is the code, that works just fine:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchPattern: request.term },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Label, value: item.Value, id: item.Id, description: item.Description }
                        }))
                    }
                });
            },
            delay: 300,
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true
        })
        .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("li>/li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("a>" + item.label + "br>div style=\"font-size:x-small;font-style:italic;\">" + item.description + "/div>/a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });
```

But if I add a second textbox to the HTML, copy the JavaScript above and change the selector and url (so in the end I have two autocomplete textboxes), then I get the following error for the second autocomplete:

```
TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined
```

With one autocomplete it works perfect, but with a second not
I can't explain why. Does anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Toby

**EDIT:**

I found the problem.

The JavaScript code is in an *.js file and the two textboxes are in two different *.thml files.

So there is only one textbox at a time and this is the problem.

Now I do the last part (with the data(...)) in the *.html file and it works fine:

```
$("#selector").autocomplete().data("autocomplete")._renderItem = renderItem;
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: You have invalid markup in `return $("li>/li>")`. Is that a typo? That could most certainly be causing issues too.

Comment: Yes I know. That's only because I didn't know how to post HTML-Tags at stackoverflow.com. So I decide to remove the first "<".

Comment: @Toby: You paste the code, select it, and then press Ctrl + K. Tada!

Comment: I've posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53885800/4187751

Comment: I've posted my solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53885800/4187751

Answer (score 6):

There was a [change in the data key naming convention](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys) in [UI 1.9](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

jQuery 1.9/1.10 removed the key `autocomplete` and added `uiAutocomplete`

```
.data("uiAutocomplete")
```

Please note: according to latest Documentation (v1.10.x) it should be .data("ui-autocomplete")
 (see: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Comment: Thanks, but I tested that already. I am also using JQuery 1.8.3 and JQuery UI 1.8.24.

Comment: @Toby your selector `$("#")` could the also a problem... looks like you missed id after `#`

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem, see above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's actually `.data('ui-autocomplete')` rather than `.data('uiAutocomplete')`. Please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The other day, I encountered the same issue, but it had nothing to do with the version I was using but simply that the element being aucomplete-ed did not exist! Try

```
alert($('...').length);
```

and make sure it is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the below mentioned line

> .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

instate of

> .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

as per the documentation available at Jquery site [JQuery AutoComplete Funtionality](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) you will find this code.

from upgraded version of jquery 1.10 they have made change in code.
hope this will help you.