# How tocheck if emojioneArea is loaded?

Tags: javascript, emoji, emojione

How can check if emojioneArea is loaded and converted the textarea into the contenteditable div?

I want to load jQuery autocomplete for the contenteditable div of the emojioneArea but the problem that I getting an error

> TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined

I solve this by adding a `setTimeout` (1 second) until emojioneArea loaded and then loaded the jQuery autocomplete but this is not a professional solution.

Comment: please share code to debug easily

Comment: possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934073/typeerror-autocomplete-data-is-undefined